# Length of 2d list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a 2D list, for example `mylist =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.

Is there any way I can use `len()` function such that I can calculate the lengths of array indices? For example:

```
len(mylist[0:3])
len(mylist[1:3])
len(mylist[0:1])
```

Should give:

```
9
6
3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`length = sum([len(arr) for arr in mylist])`

```
sum([len(arr) for arr in mylist[0:3]]) = 9
sum([len(arr) for arr in mylist[1:3]]) = 6
sum([len(arr) for arr in mylist[2:3]]) = 3
```

Sum the length of each list in `mylist` to get the length of all elements.
This will only work correctly if the list is 2D.  If some elements of `mylist` are not lists, who knows what will happen...

Additionally, you could bind this to a function:

```
len2 = lambda l: sum([len(x) for x in l])
len2(mylist[0:3]) = 9
len2(mylist[1:3]) = 6
len2(mylist[2:3]) = 3
```

Comment: No need to use a list comprehension. A generator is faster.

Comment: @MattBryant Of course. `sum(len(arr) for arr in mylist[0:3])` is faster than `sum([len(arr) for arr in mylist[0:3]])`

Comment: I was under the impression generators are better for memory usage but slower than list comprehensions if the list will fit into RAM.

Comment: Timing in Python 2.7.4:
python -m timeit -s "seq = [1]*1000" "sum([x for x in seq])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.3 usec per loop                                                                
python -m timeit -s "seq = [1]*1000" "sum(x for x in seq)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.2 usec per loop

Comment: @MattBryant: For smaller loops it is a little slower, but for larger lists the generator will always be faster due to the time it takes to create a list.

Comment: Indeed, for long lists a generator tends to be faster. More importantly, it produces less syntactic clutter.

Comment: Ok, I can agree with that.  However, you should clarify that 100 million iterations is still considered a small loop, as a list comprehension remains dramatically faster up to that point in my testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the list, then call `len` on it:

```
>>> mylist=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> import collections
>>> def flatten(l):
...     for el in l:
...         if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
...             for sub in flatten(el):
...                 yield sub
...         else:
...             yield el
...
>>> len(list(flatten(mylist)))
9
>>> len(list(flatten(mylist[1:3])))
6
>>> len(list(flatten(mylist[0:1])))
3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to calculate the length of array indices like this, this can also handle the scenario when you pass in something like `mylist[0:0]`:

```
def myLen(myList):
    return reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, [len(x) for x in myList], 0)

myLen(mylist[0:3]) = 9
myLen(mylist[1:3]) = 6
myLen(mylist[0:1]) = 3
myLen(mylist[0:0]) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @Haidro's answer, which works for arbitrary nesting, but I dislike the creation of the intermediate list.  Here's a variant that avoids that.

```
try:
    reduce
except NameError:
    # python3 - reduce is in functools, there is no basestring
    from functools import reduce
    basestring = str

import operator
import collections

def rlen(item):
    """
    rlen - recursive len(), where the "length" of a non-iterable
    is just 1, but the length of anything else is the sum of the
    lengths of its sub-items.
    """
    if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable):
        # A basestring is an Iterable that contains basestrings,
        # i.e., it's endlessly recursive unless we short circuit
        # here.
        if isinstance(item, basestring):
            return len(item)
        return reduce(operator.add, (rlen(x) for x in item), 0)
    return 1
```

For the heck of it I've included a generator-driven, fully-recursive `flatten` as well.  Note that this time there's a harder decision to make about strings (the short circuit above is trivially correct since as `len(some_string) == sum(len(char) for char in some_string)`).

```
def flatten(item, keep_strings=False):
    """
    Recursively flatten an iterable into a series of items.  If given
    an already flat item, just returns it.
    """
    if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable):
        # We may want to flatten strings too, but when they're
        # length 1 we have to terminate recursion no matter what.
        if isinstance(item, basestring) and (len(item) == 1 or keep_strings):
            yield item
        else:
            for elem in item:
                for sub in flatten(elem, keep_strings):
                    yield sub
    else:
        yield item
```

If you don't need arbitrary nesting—if you're always sure that this is just a list of lists (or list of tuples, tuple of lists, etc)—the "best" method is probably the simple "sum of generator" variant of @Matt Bryant's answer:

```
len2 = lambda lst: sum(len(x) for x in lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about `len(ast.flatten(lst))`?  only works in py2k afaik

It's

```
from compiler import ast
len(ast.flatten(lst))
```

since

```
ast.flatten([1,2,3]) == [1,2,3]
ast.flatten(mylist[0:2]) == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ast.flatten(mylist) == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```